# Get bigint from Microsoft SQL Server with SOCI

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, biginteger, soci

I am trying to get a `bigint` value (named "NUM" in my example) that comes from my database (Microsoft SQL Server). In the following code, I am trying to get it as an `int` even if I know that an `int` is smaller than a `bigint` but the cast always fails. I also tried to get it as a `long long int` and as some other types of variable but I am always getting the same problem at runtime as shown below.

```
try
{
    session sql(odbc, "...");
    rowset<row> rs = (sql.prepare << "SELECT MAX(NUM) AS MAX_NUM FROM T1");

    for (rowset<row>::const_iterator it = rs.begin(); it != rs.end(); ++it)
    {
        row const& row = *it;

        cout << "MAX_NUM: " << row.get<int>("MAX_NUM") << endl;
    }

}
catch (exception const &e)
{
    cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

I have also tried the following getters:

```
cout << "MAX_NUM: " << row.get<long>("MAX_NUM") << endl;
cout << "MAX_NUM: " << row.get<long long>("MAX_NUM") << endl;
cout << "MAX_NUM: " << row.get<long long int>("MAX_NUM") << endl;
```

All my tests print the same error when I run my application:

```
Error: std::bad_cast
```

My question is : What is the correct way to get this value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best solution but it is the only one I found that works:

```
cout << "MAX_NUM: " << row.get<double>("MAX_NUM") << endl;
```